# Protobuf to scala conversion

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

I have in protobuf

```
message ResultsPb{
    repeated int32 Result = 1;
}
```

and  the corresponding in scala

```
Results: List[Int]
```

I’m new to this and I’m having a hard time finding the proper way to convert from one to the other. Here is what I've come up with so far but not sure at all of that. First def doesn't build, second def do build.

```
def toResults(resultsPb: Option[ResultsPb]): List[Int] ={
  List[Int](resultsPb.Result)
}

def fromResults(results: List[Int]): Option[ResultsPb] ={
  Some(ResultsPb (results.toSeq))
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In `toResults`, you are passing in an `Option`, and then not treating it as an `Option`, but trying to access the `Result` directly. Your compiler should have told you this. You may want `resultsPb match { case Some(rp) => List( rp.Result ); case None => Nil }`

Answer (score 0):

```
def toResults(resultsPb: Option[ResultsPb]): List[Int] ={
  resultsPb.toList.flatMap(_.Result)
}

def fromResults(results: List[Int]): Option[ResultsPb] ={
  Some(results).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(t => ResultPb(t))
}
```

**Update**

So, to convert optional proto class to its argument you need

- to check that option is not empty
- extract data from class

this could be done as Bob proposed (with pattern matching), or simplier with flatMap (but before you need to convert Option to Seq/List to satisfy type check)

In second method, again you can do it with if statement (checking if List is empty), with matching (checking the same with "case _ :: Nil => ... case Nil =>") or as I proposed with filtering empty result and getting None automatically in this case.

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so.